# download multiple files over https with username and password

Tags: r

I have a data frame `dat` that includes an ID variable and several variables with URLs to download sound files.

```
dat <- data.frame(id=c(1, 2, 3, 4),
                  recording1=c("someURL", "someURL", "someURL", "someURL"),
                  recording2=c("someURL", "someURL", "someURL", "someURL"),
                  recording3=c("someURL", "someURL", "someURL", "someURL"),
                  recording4=c("someURL", "someURL", "someURL", "someURL"))
```

I need to download each file (basically every cell of a n x 5-1 matrix) and save the file with the column name and observation ID. Something like:

```
for (i in 2:length(dat)) {
  for (r in 1:nrow(dat)) {
    download.file(as.character(dat[r,i]), 
                  destfile=paste(names(dat)[i], dat$id[r], "wav", sep="."),
                  method="curl"))
  }
}
```

According to the help for `download.file()`, this function does not support https. How can I modify my approach to use https AND include a username (email) and password?

```
sessionInfo()
# R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
# Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0 (64-bit)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give the `httr` package a go and use the `write_disk` option to `GET`:

```
GET(as.character(dat[r, i]), 
    authenticate("username", "password"),
    write_disk(destfile=paste(names(dat)[i], dat$id[r], "wav", sep=".")))
```

(Updated to reflect the need for authentication which the OP reminded me & fixed in comments)

Comment: This works great. I just added `authenticate("username", "password"),` before `write_disk`.

Comment: Argh. Sorry about that. I added that to the answer for posterity.

Comment: Note: `write_disk` has an argument `path` and not `destfile`