# Download same file from devices with static IPs needing username and password (windows or Mac)

Tags: r, windows, macos

I have 20 air quality sensors with unique IP addresses which log data and store it to a file called ABCD.txt (same name on each device). Each sensor is connected to a local mobile hot-spot and so is my laptop. I'd like to download the file from each one of the sensors without having to go into windows explorer/safari on Mac, typing in the IP address, username and password each time and manually dragging it to my desktop, renaming it and then repeating 20 times every day. Is there a way of scripting this, say in R?

I have a data.frame of IP addresses, names of devices:

```
    data.frame(IPAddress=c("\\192.168.43.92\airvisual"),
passWord=c("aaaaaaaa"),
nameIwantToGiveFile=c("A12"))
```

This looks promising, but not quite what I'm after:
[download multiple files over https with username and password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26078383/download-multiple-files-over-https-with-username-and-password)

Comment: Perhaps you could map the folders and then download via the regular route? https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/265459/HOW-TO-ACCESS-A-SHARED-FOLDER-VIA-COMMAND-LINE Or there may be a more native way of specifying username and password to access network folders.

Comment: From windows how you are accessing the file on the sensor. Are you using CIFS,ftp or http?
And what kind of authentication it is?

Comment: Http. I open windows explorer, type in \\192.168.43.XXX\airvisual and hit enter. A login window appears where I type in my username and password and hit enter.

Comment: @Logu can you clarify what you mean by authentication please? The sensors' documentation doesn't have anything mentioning this.

Answer (score 1):

@HCAI if you are accessing like this \192.168.43.XXX\airvisual, then chances are you are using CIFS (windows file sharing) not http.

If you are able to access using the browser http://192.168.43.XXX, then you should be able to use "curl" and automate this.

Assuming the authentication is of http basic scheme

```
curl -u <username>:<passwd> http://192.168.43.XXX/path/to/the/file -o <newfilename>
```

Authentication means the credential to access the resource (here username and password)

For cifs create a .bat script something like this

```
net use F: \\192.168.43.XXX\airvisual /user:Your_user_name Your_password /persistent:Yes
copy F:\<filename> path\to\the\requirelocation\sensor1.txt
net use F: /delete
```

Comment: You are right it's not http but CIFS. I thought it was http because on the mac I access them via safari but in fact they open in file explorer. On the sensors there's a mention of samba: "change samba password". Is this any help?

Comment: Create a .bat script something like this and try to use it. If this works you could add it to the scheduler. `net use F: \\192.168.43.XXX\airvisual /user:Your_user_name Your_password /persistent:Yes
copy F:\<filename> path\to\the\requirelocation\sensor1.txt
net use F: /delete `