# 401 error from download.file in for-loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop, http, http-status-code-401

I am trying to download a series of raster tiles from the USGS website [here](https://e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov/MEASURES/GFCC30TC.003/2015.01.01/). I am using R and hope to accomplish this via a for-loop like below. Note - I am working on a Mac.

```
tdir = tempdir()

tiles = c("p017r030",
          "p016r030",
          "p017r031",
          "p016r031",
          "p015r030",
          "p014r030",
          "p014r031")

for(k in unique(tiles)){
    tileurl=paste("https://e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov/MEASURES/GFCC30TC.003/2015.01.01/GFCC30TC_",k,"_TC_2015.zip",sep="")
    download.file(tileurl,destfile = file.path(paste(tdir,"Canopy",k,".zip",sep="")))
    unzip(file.path(paste(tdir,"Canopy",k,".zip",sep=""),exdir=tdir))
    Canopy_tile = paste("Canopy_tile",k,sep="")
    assign(Canopy_tile,terra::rast(paste(tdir,"Canopy",k,".zip",sep="")))}
```

However, I am left with an error because a USGS log in is required the first time you attempt to access these data. Error shown below. Is there a way to add the log in step into the for-loop, presumably only for the first time through the loop?

```
#> Warning in download.file(tileurl, destfile = file.path(paste(tdir,
#> "Canopy", : cannot open URL 'https://urs.earthdata.nasa.gov/oauth/authorize?
#> scope=uid&app_type=401&client_id=ijpRZvb9qeKCK5ctsn75Tg&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fe4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov%2Foauth&state=aHR0cHM6Ly9lNGZ0bDAxLmNyLnVzZ3MuZ292L01FQVNVUkVTL0dGQ0MzMFRDLjAwMy8yMDE1LjAxLjAxL0dGQ0MzMFRDX3AwMTdyMDMwX1RDXzIwMTUuemlw':
#> HTTP status was '401 Unauthorized'
#> Error in download.file(tileurl, destfile = file.path(paste(tdir, "Canopy", : cannot open URL 'https://e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov/MEASURES/GFCC30TC.003/2015.01.01/GFCC30TC_p017r030_TC_2015.zip'
```

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43580133/how-to-use-rselenium-to-login-to-a-website-on-windows-machine) helps?

Comment: Sorry, I should've made this clear. I'm working on a Mac machine.

Comment: Have you considered `rvest`? or possibly even just `httr::GET` using `httr::authenticate`?

Comment: See https://httr.r-lib.org/reference/authenticate.html

Comment: Or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26078383/download-multiple-files-over-https-with-username-and-password).

Comment: Thanks for the pointers @Julian & @r2evans. I ended up using `httr::GET`